# Python: GIT commit programmatically

Tags: python, django, git

I try to make `git commits` programmatically right in `Python`/`Django`. The problem I encounter is the syntax of the command. The message of a commit is a variable, that may contain several words. So, I tried to do it this way:

```
command('git commit -m "%s"'%msg) # command is a custom function that calls 
                                  # system Popen function
```

If I then make a `push` command to a remote repository at `github`, then first what I see, is that commit messages are in double quotes like "Test" and another problem is that if a message contains two or more words like "Test message", then it is not even executed. In other words, in a situation like

```
msg = "Test message"
command('git commit -m "%s"'%msg)
```

Nothing happens.

Comment: What are you writing a new wrapper for? There's already gitpython.

Comment: First of all, I do not need a behemot, I just need several simplest commands in my app. And besides, when I tested gittle and gitpython I encountered a number of problems like getting the list of modified files etc.

Comment: That's your issue, not gitpython's issue.

Comment: For example, in gittle instead of a list of modified files I get some garbage with a command repo.modified_files (probably, I did something wrong, but still I have this issue), while in gitpython I do not even see a command to list modified files. I know something about diffs, but IMHO that looks just terrible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used git from command line, too. This is how I do it [here](https://github.com/niccokunzmann/gh-pages-edit/blob/master/command_line.py).

```
import subprocess

def git_commit(message):
    return subprocess.check_output(['git', 'commit',  '-m', message])
```

If nothing happens it might be that you need to add the changed files first.

```
def git_add(file_path):
    return subprocess.check_output(['git', 'add', file_path])
```

Or you add and commit all.

```
def git_commit_all(message):
    return subprocess.check_output(['git', 'commit', '-am', message])
```